# err empty response when trying to insert into mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, runtime-error, mean

I'm quite new to the mean stack and am trying to create an application that has two data collections, 'users' and 'courses'. For the users I have used an login-and registration example and it works fine. For the courses I have tried to re-create the same structure (so all files named including the same course has a similar one named user) for the courses but am having trouble with creating a new course and adding it to the database. I get ERR EMPTY RESPONSE but cannot understand why and how to correct it. Below is some (compressed) code, let me know if more information is needed.  I have excluded client-side code since I know the error is on the server-side. Server.js is called with the following command from client-side:

```
function Create(course) {
return $http.post('/api/courses', course).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}
```

**server.js**

```
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ secret: config.secret, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true           }));

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }).unless({ path: ['/api/users/authenticate', '/api/users/register'] }));

// routes
app.use('/login', require('./controllers/login.controller'));
app.use('/register', require('./controllers/register.controller'));
app.use('/app', require('./controllers/app.controller'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./controllers/api/users.controller'));
app.use('/api/courses', require('./controllers/api/courses.controller.js'));
//app.use('/registercourse', require('./controllers/create.course.controller'));

// make '/app' default route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return res.redirect('/app');
});

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

// start server
var server = app.listen(port, ipaddress);
```

**controllers/api/courses.controller**

I don't think the error is in this file since it successfully calls CourseService, but I could be wrong.

```
var config = require('config.json');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var CourseService = require('services/course.service');

router.post('/', createCourse);

module.exports = router;

function createCourse(req,res){
CourseService.create(req.body)
    .then(function(){
        res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
}
```

**services/course.services**
I think the error is in the file since it does not completely behave the same as services/user.services do. In services/user.services, **db.users** becomes bold and is connected to db.bind('users') but this does not work in this file, for db.courses it looks like **db**.courses. Have tried introducing a namespace, which seems to connect db.courses with db.bind('course') but I still get the same error.

```
var config = require('config.json');
var _ = require('lodash');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Q = require('q');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');

var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mean-stack-registration-login-example";
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL){
    connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + "studycontrol";
}
var db = mongo.db(connectionString, { native_parser: true });

db.bind('courses');

var service = {};
service.create = create;
module.exports = service;

module.exports = service;

function create(courseParam) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

   //validation
    db.courses.findOne(
        {courseName: courseParam.courseName}),
        function (err, course) {
            if (err) deferred.reject(err);
            if (course) {
                deferred.reject('Coursename "' + courseParam.courseName + '" is already taken');
            } else {
                createCourse()
            }
        };

    function createCourse() {
        var course = courseParam
        db.courses.insert(
            course,
            function (err, doc) {
                if (err) deferred.reject(err);
                deferred.resolve();
            });
    }

    return deferred.promise;

}
```

Comment: To start with, I suggest you don't use defer at all and use the built in mongoose promises instead. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: Also returning the error as a json object instead of using send might give you the stack trace. Either do res.status(400).json(err) or log the stack trace with console.log(err.stack); The stack trace should tell you where the error is happening.